# Extend background on two of three monitors

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, desktop-customization

I have three monitors (two with the same size) and I'd like to set the same extended background for the two monitors with the same size and I'd like to set another background on the different sized desktop. How can I manage to do that? I've been trying for half an hour but I can only set a different background for each monitor or extend the backgrounds through all the screens (which is the worst choice ever since the third monitor is in vertical and sized 900x1440 (width x height).

Comment: What operating system or version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I wrote it in the tags, I'm using Windows 8.1 (Don't even ask me why, I'm a Linux user)

Comment: Sorry, I missed your tag. Have you already tried this: Rightclick on the Desktop, select Personalize
At the bottom - click on Desktop Background
Picture Positions - Select Span

Comment: You'll probably need to make a single custom image that fits your desktop, with sections that are different for each monitor.

Comment: @omg_dudewtf yes I tried and I can only set a whole extended image for the three screens or an image for each screen

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 if I can't find other answers I think I'll go with your solution